# Как переименовать метки на оси координат в matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Есть график:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def deg_to_rad(deg):
    return (deg * np.pi) / 180

X = np.arange(360)
Y = np.sin(deg_to_rad(X))

plt.plot(X,Y)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно переименовать метки по оси Х, а именно координату `90` переименовать в `п/2`, координату `180` в `п`, координату `270` в `3п/2` и координату `360` в `2п`, остальные метки вообще убрать.

Так как метки с координатами `90`, `180`, `270`, `360` изначально вообще отсутствуют, их нужно каким то образом еще и добавить.

Как их добавить и переименовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** используем градусы вместо радиан для оси абсцисс и переписываем метки (Latex) вручную

```
X = np.arange(-180, 181)
Y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(X))

plt.plot(X,Y)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

points = np.array([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0,  np.pi/2, np.pi])
labels = [r'-$\pi$', r'-$\frac{\pi}{2}$', '$0$', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$\pi$']
plt.xticks(np.rad2deg(points), labels)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно )

Comment: Для радиан понятно, но не могу понять как для градусов шкалу Х переименовать ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, сейчас попробую...

Comment: было бы супер )

Comment: Именно то что нужно!